# How to create a group of contact folders in outlook via c#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, addressbook, contacts

I've been searching for a while, how to create a **Contact Group** in Outlook view of the Address book. In this case I don't mean a contact group to send an email to a lot of people (*i.e. not a mailing list*). It's only the view of the Address book within Outlook. A group can contain a number of **Contact Folders**.

Does anybody have an idea or some information to solve this problem via c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to leverage the Contacts [`NavigationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.navigationmodule.aspx) (*[`ContactsModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.contactsmodule.aspx)*) via [`Explorer.NavigationPane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868233.aspx) to control the **Contact Groups**.

```
Outlook.Folder contacts = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.ContactsModule module = Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleContacts) as Outlook.ContactsModule;
Outlook.NavigationGroup group = module.NavigationGroups.Create("Custom Group"); // creates contact group
group.NavigationFolders.Add(contacts.Folders.Add("Business Contacts")); // adds folders to group
```

Comment: Just a small hint, if someone else has the same problem: If you programatically create a new folder and the group folder view (e.g. My Tasks) is not refreshing properly, this solution fixes this as well (just by retrieving the default navigation group GetDefaultNavigationGroup)

Comment: @mnkypete This does not work in Outlook 2010. Calling GetDefaultNavigationGroup does nothing. Folder list does not get updated (at least for contacts).