# Creating contact folders with Outlook REST API?

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

Is it possible to create contact folders with Outlook REST API? I've looked into the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations) for Outlook Contacts API and found only references to fetching existing contact folders (even in the beta version).

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992768/how-to-create-a-group-of-contact-folders-in-outlook-via-c-sharp) seem to focus on using C# and probably some specific SDK for that. I'm using Python, so that wouldn't work for me. I haven't found, both on StackOverflow and through Google in general, any definitive answers to this question. From the lack of any mentions in the docs, I'd assume it's not possible, but just wanted to get a definitive and/or official answer on that matter, if possible. Also please let me know if I missed something during my research.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @Eric Legault's answer it gave me an insight to try something blindly. Even though the docs do not state it, you can create a folder by doing a POST to the contact folders endpoint with DisplayName property in the body.

So do 
`POST https://outlook.office.com/api/<version>/me/contactfolders` with `{"DisplayName": "folder_name"}` in the request's body and it will work, returning the usual `201 Created` response code.

This worked for me in both v2.0 and beta endpoints.

As of this writing, Outlook Contacts' UI (self-entitled Outlook People) is terrible and not user-friendly at all (either that or I just suck at understanding it), so I actually don't know how to create or delete contact folders through it, but I'm glad the REST API does the job :)

Comment: Yep, this works. We're working on consolidating our docs with the Graph docs at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_contactfolders to address this omission. And thanks for the feedback on the People UI (I assume you mean in the web client!). I'll pass it along :)

Comment: @JasonJohnston No problem! Thanks for the answer once again and for passing along the feedback (yes, I mean the web client through outlook.com). Didn't mean to be rude about it, but it really makes no sense to me. If I delete a contact, it maintains the selection on the deleted contact even though it no longer exists. If I want to delete another, I need to select all contacts, then unselect all contacts and then select the contact I want to delete, because I cant unselect directly a contact that no longer exists. These kinds of issues seem to be all over the UI :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a create folder operation, although it seems [specific to Mail folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#CreateFolders) and doesn't take any parameters that can specify a folder type.  It's possible it may take on the same item type as the parent folder, but I'm  not certain.

Otherwise there is a create method specific for Contact folders in the Graph API; see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contactfolder_post_childfolders.

If you want a Python specific SDK, see: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python. Code samples: https://github.com/search?q=python+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories

FYI, you can use any code platform to work with the Office 365 or Graph APIs, as long as they support REST.

Comment: While your answer did not give me a direct answer to how to create a contacts folder using Outlook REST API, it did inspire me to try creating a folder using the standard params the Outlook APIs use (albeit using different endpoints). Even though the docs do not state it, you can create a folder by doing a POST to the contact folders endpoint with DisplayName property in the body. Thanks for the insight!